# Eclipse web service NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

Now, I want to create web service based on the same WSDL file, but using Axis2 1.7.0

I got the following error during WSDL-to-code generation:
Exception occurred during code generation for the WSDL  : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema

I understand from the release note that Axis2 1.7.0 has upgraded its XMLSchema hence it is backward incompatible with Axis2 1.6.x. But I am not sure how can I relate this to my problem.

**

> From what I understand, Axis2 complains that XMLSchema is not present.
>   So, I import XMLSchema jar into my project build path. But the same
>   error still occurs.

**

can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should import xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar to build path, and delete old version Xmlschema-1.7. then rebuild the service.

That's work for me.